# Additional row with empty header in matrix in power bi

Tags: matrix, powerbi, row

The problem is probably trivial but unfortunately I can't figure it out. Here are two basics tables:
[image]

I tried to create the matrix based on the selected ID (from the Table2) with values from Table1. I created a measure "% Margin" (margin divided by revenue) and tried to add this to the matrix with ID from Table2. Every time besides ID from Table2 I got one additional row with empty ID. Anyone has an idea how to get rid it off? The rest of the matrix is correct.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the columns *ID* and *ID Table2* are NOT identical.

Comment: ID Table2 contains some values from ID Table1. E.g. ID from table1 is {1;2;3;4;5], ID from table2 is {2;4;5}

Comment: So the blank ID Table2 refers to all ID's of Table1 that are not in Table2. What's the idea of having this Table2 anyhow?

Comment: I need to present just chosen values from Table1 so that's why I created Table2 that contains necessary ID. And then I need to also rank these chosen values. I don't want to take all ID from Table1

Comment: It's better to add a new column "Show" with zeros and ones (or any other category) to Table1 and then filter by that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a separate static table, simply add a new column to you table and use that to filter your data for the report.

Here's how this would look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peter, it got clearer a bit